# Alineación de contenido CSS

Tags: html, css

Tengo un mini-proyecto con algunos iconos que viene acompañados por texto. Éstos están bien alineados con el texto, pero no entre sí. ¿Habría alguna forma de "tabular" estos iconos para que queden alineado por iconos?

Este es mi código y el cómo está ahora:

```css
p, h1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid-item cuatro">

        <h1><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px; color: DarkSlateBlue" id="AnimacionIconosG4">info</i> Hola</h1>
        <p><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i> Hola1<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i> Hola2 <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i> Hola3 </p>
        <p><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>Holacomoestas<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i> Hola5 </p>
        <p><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>Holaquetal<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>Hola7</p>
      </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Y quiero que quede así:

[image: Alineacion]

También añadir algo de espacio entre icono e icono.

He probado con distintos códigos, pero sin resultado. (`align-items: center`, `align-self: center`, `justify-items: center` ... )

También, otro problema que tengo que está relacionado también con la alineación, es en la parte del footer.

Tengo un texto (que aparece a un lado y no hay forma de moverlo al centro) y unos iconos justo debajo que conseguí centrarlos, pero no consigo centrar el texto.

```css
.flex-container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   background-color: none;
   justify-content: center;
}

.boton1{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.boton2{
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
}

a.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: DarkSlateBlue;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, DarkSlateBlue , #8980c4);
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
}
.button:hover {background-color: #736aad}

.button:active {
  background-color: #5404c8;
  box-shadow: 0 3px #666;
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

a.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

a.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

a.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

a.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="grid-item cinco">
  <p style="font-weight: bold"> Hola que tal: </p>
  <div class="flex-container">
        <a href="boton1.com"> <img src="boton1.png" class="boton1" title="Boton1"></a>
        <a href="boton2.com"> <img src="boton2.png" class="boton2" title="Boton2"></a>
  <a href="prueba.pdf" title="Descarga aquí prueba" class="button"><span>Prueba PDF</span></a>
  </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

He probado a añadir el texto dentro del `flex`, pero me aparecía al lado de los iconos. Y aunque le metiese tantos `<br>` como código había, no me hacía caso.

Comment: cada columana de texto tiene que tener un ancho definido, suponiendo en el body el 100%, cada columna seria de 33%

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modifiqué un poco tu **HTML** para ajustarlo a un sistema de **filas** y **columnas**. Yo usé `display: flex` pero también se podría haber solucionado tratando el contenido como si de una tabla se tratara por medio de `display: table`, `display: table-row` y `display: table-cell`.

```css
h1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 450px;
}

.fila {
  display: flex;
}

.columna {
  display: flex;
  width: 33%;
  margin: 0px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid-item cuatro">
      <div class="fila">
        <h1><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px; color: DarkSlateBlue" id="AnimacionIconosG4">info</i> Hola</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="fila">
        <p class="columna"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i> Hola1</p>
        <p class="columna"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i> Hola2</p>
        <p class="columna"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i> Hola3</p>
      </div>
      <div class="fila">
        <p class="columna"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>Holacomoestas</p>
        <p class="columna"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i> Hola5</p>
      </div>
      <div class="fila">
        <p class="columna"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>Holaquetal</p>
        <p class="columna"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>Hola7</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```